# trouble positioning div below several float left divs

Tags: css, css-float

It's a bit tricky to describe css issues, but I'll do my best.

Below my nav bar, I have a container div.  It is set to 80% wide.

In the container div, I have a box-wrapper div that contains four divs that are all `float:left;`  They Are that way so that They can drop down one at a time depending on the users browser size.

Below the box wrapper is another box-wrapper2 div that contains four divs that are not floated.

They appear one above the other.

The problem is that for some reason the box-wrapper2 div is shifting up and behind the box wrapper.  I want it positioned below the top wrapper.

How do I do this?

Here is the page I'm talking about:
http://www.rattletree.com/index2.php

If you use firebug and hover over the first "programDetail" div, you can see that it is going up and under the above div.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this link for more options to solve your problem: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Option 1.
I believe you can set your container divs to `overflow:hidden;` which will clear them and bump the second container down so there is no overlap.

Option 2.
You should set a div below your floats that clears them. There are several ways to do this, but the simplest is to set another div below your floats with the css `clear:both`

*Side note: Be sure to also give your clearing div a `height:0;line-height:0;display:block;` to insure it doesn't add any funky space at the bottom of your containers*

---

**EDIT:**
**Since this question was last asked (and answered) new ways of achieving the desired effect have changed. A common practice is to have a container div with the following styles:**

```
.container:before, 
.container:after {
 display: table;
 line-height: 0;
 content: "";
}
.container:after {
 clear: both;
}
```

This method is used by popular frameworks (e.g. - Zurb Foundation & Twitter Bootstrap)

Comment: The clear does the trick.  I still don't fully understand what the heck clear really does in this case.  It seems like a bad name for the result. :-)

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable solution but option 2 adds unnecessary markup to the html document.

Comment: @Kyle, I definitely agree. Option 2 is definitely the rough way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, I believe you should apply these styles...

```
.boxWrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.programDetailWrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  It breaks the divs out of the container div.