# Whats the CSS to make something go to the next line in the page?

Tags: css, positioning

How can I make an element automatically be positioned on a new line in the page? In HTML I could use `<br>`, but how do I add something like a **line-break** in CSS?

Say I have the following code for example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
   <span id="elementId">consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
   Magni totam velit ex delectus fuga fugit</p>
```

The span is still positioned on the same line as the rest of the text. How can I move the span text on a new line purely through CSS?

Another example is when using `display: inline-block` or `float`:

```
<div class="smalldiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="smalldiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="smalldiv" id="elementId">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="smalldiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

.smalldiv {
    display: inline-block; // OR
    float: left;
}
```

How can I move one of the `<div>`s on a new line to create a new row?

Comment: I...think I'd disagree with you; what is the 'something'?

Comment: Have you even bothered to look it up? Unless your question is more complicated as David thinks it may be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [trouble positioning div below several float left divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414321/trouble-positioning-div-below-several-float-left-divs)

Comment: Flexbox: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There are two options that I can think of, but without more details, I can't be sure which is the better:

```
#elementId {
    display: block;
}
```

This will force the element to a 'new line' *if* it's not on the same line as a floated element.

```
#elementId {
     clear: both;
}
```

This will force the element to clear the floats, and move to a 'new line.'

In the case of the element being on the same line as another that has `position` of `fixed` or `absolute` nothing will, so far as I know, force a 'new line,' as those elements are removed from the document's normal flow.

Comment: what about if the parent element is an inline element. This doesn't seem to work if that's the case.

Answer (score 10):

Have the element display as a block:

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends why the something is on the same line in the first place.

`clear` in the case of floats, `display: block` in the case of inline content naturally flowing, nothing will defeat `position: absolute` as the previous element will be taken out of the normal flow by it.